# Resize all pictures in Workbook to a fixed height in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to resize all pictures in a workbook with hundreds of sheets (some that contain jpgs/pngs embedded or charts, some that do not). I want all charts and pictures to have the same width and NOT have a pagebreak in the middle of a figure, but not certain how to do this. Here is my code so far, which does not seem to work...

```
'Resize all the pictures to fit the page while maintaining aspect ratio
With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim pict As Shape

    On Error Resume Next

    For Each WS In Worksheets
        For Each pict In WS.Shapes
            If pict.Type = msoPicture Or pict.Type = msoGraphic Or pict.Type =     msoIgxGraphic And pict.Width > 1 And pict.Height > 1 Then
                WS.Activate
                pict.ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
                pict.ShapeRange.Height = 250

                n = n + 1
            End If
        Next pict
    Next WS

    MsgBox n & " pictures were resized to fit the page successfully."
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With
```

Comment: Maybe comment out the error line so you can find out where the error is.Maybe activate the ws right after `for each ws in sheets`

Comment: ① Never use `On Error Resume Next` without proper error handling. Using this line as you did just hides error messages, but the errors still occur, you just cannot see them. Remove it completely or implement an error handling instead. Otherwise you cannot debug/fix your code at all. ② *"does not seem to work"* is almost the worst error description you can use. Instead please always *describe* what happens. Otherwise that's a useless information. You wouln't post here if it would work, but we need to know what you expected and what happened instead, eg. what error messages and where.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `ShapeRange`from

```
pict.LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
pict.Height = 250
```

I'm not sure how that works with grouped objects, but at least you get something.

Comment: This works, but some of the pictures still break across pages when printed. Is there any way to "force" the pictures to print to one page?

Comment: I tried this, but doesn't work:
      For Each xWorksheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
      xWorksheet.PageSetup.Orientation = xlLandscape
      xWorksheet.Zoom = False
      xWorksheet.PageSetup.PrintTitleRows = "$A$1:$AZ$1"
      xWorksheet.PageSetup.FitToPagesWide = 1
      xWorksheet.PageSetup.FitToPagesTall = 1
      xWorksheet.PageSetup.FitToPagesTall = False

Comment: I don't think you can force them to be on a single page automatically. You will have to use some kind of logic to force them to stay away from the danger zone. Easiest way is to move it up (i.e decrease top value) if it is above a threshold value.

Answer (score 0):

First, set the page view.

```
ActiveWindow.View = xlPageBreakPreview
```

Second, you need to have data in any cell to do page breaks.

```
.Range("a10000") = "d"
```

Then place the picture in the page break cell.

```
Sub test()
'Resize all the pictures to fit the page while maintaining aspect ratio
Dim Ws As Worksheet

ActiveWindow.View = xlPageBreakPreview
With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim pict As Shape
    Dim rngT As Range
    'On Error Resume Next

    For Each Ws In Worksheets
        Ws.Range("a10000") = "d"
        n = 0
        For Each pict In Ws.Shapes
            If pict.Type = msoPicture Or pict.Type = msoGraphic Or pict.Type = msoIgxGraphic And pict.Width > 1 And pict.Height > 1 Then
                Ws.Activate
                pict.LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
                If n = 0 Then
                    Set rngT = Ws.Range("a1")
                Else
                    Set rngT = Ws.HPageBreaks(n).Location
                End If
                With pict
                    .Top = rngT.Top
                    .Left = rngT.Left
                    .Height = 250
                End With
                n = n + 1
            End If
        Next pict
        Ws.Range("a10000") = Empty
    Next Ws

    MsgBox n & " pictures were resized to fit the page successfully."
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I get an "out of range" error on this line:
                    Set rngT = Ws.HPageBreaks(n).Location

Comment: If you have a lot of pictures, increase the range further.  TO  range("a20000")

Comment: I changed it to "a50000" but same error happens. Any ideas?